# How to add words/strings in lines from a list?

Tags: python, string, list, loops, printing

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jliLf.png)
[the Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JnNF.png)

I'm trying to add different words from a **list** to lines in order. However, I am stuck with it. Can you please tell me how to proceed? I am getting a type error, and couldn't get my output.

The output that I'm trying to get:

```
it starts with: one or more.
it starts with: two or more.
it starts with: three or more.
```

The code that I tried:

```
a=["one","two","three"]

for i in a:
  print("it starts with: " + a[i] + "or more")
```

The result I'm getting:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: `i` is already the value. `for i in a: print("it starts with: " + i + " or more")`

Answer (score 4):

`i` is already the element you want.

In Python the expression `for i in a` assigns elements of the array `a` to the variable `i` on every pass of the loop. You don't nedd to address the elements.

```py
for i in a:
    print("it starts with: " + i + "or more")
```

Comment: Note that *a* is **not** an array. In this case it's a list. Syntactically it could be any iterable

Answer (score 2):

So the issue you're encountering is that when you tell python to take an element `i` from the list the `i` value is not the index but rather the value. So basically what your code is doing is `a["one"]` which doesn't work.
If you replace `a[i]` with just `i` it should work. Also I would recommend replacing '+' with ',' for there to be a space between your two strings and the value you're taking from a.

Answer (score 2):

i already represents each element in the list. You can use an f-string to put it into the string:

```
for i in a:
    print(f"it starts with: {i} or more")
```

Answer (score 1):

You mix-up the iteration part, here looping over the length of the list

```
a=["one","two","three"]

for i in range(len(a)):
  print("it starts with: " + a[i] + "or more")
```

Here another approach. Used a string template where `{}` represent the placeholder.

```
a=["one","two","three"]

template = "it starts with: {} or more"

print(*map(template.format, a), sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

*for* loops work with iterables

So, for example,

```
for X in Y:
    pass
```

Here, *Y* is an iterable and *X* will acquire the values from *Y* one at a time until the iterable is exhausted.

In your case, *a* is a list (an iterable) of strings.

Therefore you could simply do this:

```
a = ["one", "two", "three"]

for w in a:
    print('it starts with:', w, 'or more')
```

Note how neither f-strings nor string concatenation is required in this case. This is because multiple values can be passed to *print()* and they will be emitted separated by a single space (by default).

**Output:**

```
it starts with: one or more
it starts with: two or more
it starts with: three or more
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the other answers should fix your problem but to avoid this trivial error in the future, you should try to examine the value of the variable you're using with one of these methods:

- Adding a `print()` statement. In your case: add this after line 3
      `print(i)`
- Using debugging feature of your IDE. For example in VSCOde: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging